# Best way to Store and Search Numbers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, data-structures

I have a very large array storing some numbers. My task is to find if a particular number exists in array or not efficiently. Which algorithm and data structure I should go with?

Few assumptions:

1. Each number in array would be unique.
2. I am not concerned about where the data is found in array I just want to return true if data is found else false.

I would be using C++ as programming language.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: use `std::set`. or a sorted `std::vector` and `std::binary_search`.

Comment: Do you actually have a very large array or are you looking for a better data structure than a very large array?

Comment: What are you optimizing for, and what is the distribution of the numbers? There is no "best" way to represent a set.

Comment: Implement Hashing or use inbuilt data structure that implements Hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Constant time lookup with `unordered_set`.

There are also options of bitsets etc. Depends exactly how large is "very large" and the sparseness of the values stored compared to how many of them there actually are.

Answer (score 0):

seems *unordered_set* is suitable for your requirement.

PS: Pls remember all elements in this set are immutable

Answer (score 0):

The known best way to check if an element (number) is a member of a set (array) is to use [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). It works well if set is changing over time or if there are set operations among sets. Bloom filters are easy to implement and good implementations [are availble](http://code.google.com/p/bloom/)

If set is static (i.e. never change) the good way is to use [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). It will take time to build, but will outperform usual hash function provided by std::unordered_set